# perform checks on image width and height

Tags: php, html, css, image, function

How can I perform checks on the images width and height?

```
$image_size = getimagesize($image_temp);
```

the third element of the array shows:

```
width="1679" height="939"
```

I was wondering how I can check whether the width of the image is over 1000 and if it is, I could change the width to 1000px;

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 0th element to check the condition and generate the output yourself, e.g.:

```
$size = getimagesize($image_temp);
$width_and_height = $size[0] > 1000 ? 'width="1000"' : $size[3];
```

Or, if you'd like to keep the height:

```
$width_and_height = $size[0] > 1000 ? 'width="1000" height="'.$size[1].'"' : $size[3];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. The thing is how do i change the images's width itself? print_r($image_size); still shows 1697

Comment: What do you mean the image's width itself?

Comment: @ElmerAlmeida u can change image size using [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function,  read the provided example in there